# Translation of "Contact us" - what is the difference between "Contacta con nosotras" and "Contacte con nosotros"?

Tags: traducción, pronombres, género

I am learning Spanish and I am confused by the translation of "Contact us".

What is the difference between "Contacta con nosotras" and "Contacte con nosotros"?

And If I use Google Translate, it is "Contáctenos". Can someone please explain?

**Update from comment**: I'm writing a title.

Comment: What is the context where you want to use it? Traditionally, "Contacte con nosotros/nosotras" refers to either everybody (masculine addresses everybody in Spanish) or female.

Comment: In writing as a title. How about in speech?

Comment: What sort of title?  Could you give us more context?  My guess is you're writing something for the web.  Is it going to appear at the top of the page?  // Usually, for this sort of thing, it's best to look at some nicely done websites and see how they handled it.

Comment: You are learning Spanish and haven't learned masculine and feminine pronouns??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Contacta con nosotras" means "Contact us", but referring to a group of females. If you mean "Contact us", but are referring to a group of males (or a mixed group) it should be "Contacta con **nosotros**". It's something you'd expect to find on a blog page, an informal website, or the support page on a Social Network site, such as Twitter or Facebook, which generally don't use the formal way to refer to their users.

"Contacte con nosotros" also means "Contact us", referring to a group of males or a mixed group, but it's the formal way. It's something you'd find on a corporate website.

Since English does normally not differentiate between genders, and the formality of a sentence is usually known by context, "Contacta con nosotros", "Contacta con nosotras", "Contacte con nosotros" and "Contacte con nosotras" all translate as "Contact us", but there are many subtle differences in Spanish, and you must use the proper one every time.

Answer (score 5):

I would go for a mere ***Contacto***.

A little check on the main page of different important sites sees that *contacto* is the title for the link from the main page to this specific section:

- [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) → then, the title of the contact page is *contacta*
- [El País](http://elpais.com/estaticos/contacte/) → *contacta con nosotros*
- [Eldiario](http://www.eldiario.es/contacto/) → *contacto*

---

*Contáctenos*, *contacta con nosotros* and *contacta con nosotras* are all equivalent. *Contáctenos* uses the [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) personal pronoun *-nos* to point to nosotros/nosotras.

The difference between *nosotros* and *nosotras* is the people that this addresses to. Traditionally, the masculine is seen as the standard way to address to everybody in Spanish. However, lately it is more and more common to use both genders and make it explicit "gracias a todos y todas" and even some people go for the feminine alone.

Unless your company is just formed by women, use *nosotros* or just get rid of the complication by using *contáctanos* alone.

This also applies to speech.

For the difference between *contact**a*** and *contact**e*** (*tú* and *usted*), see [hlecuanda's thorough answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20936/1674).

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct gramatically and syntactically. As in most things Spanish, this has important regional variations in meaning.

In general the only difference between these two forms, is the mode of address.

- ***Contacte con nosotros*** Is *generally* (regional variance details to follow below) the **formal mode of address**
- ***Contacta con nosotros*** Is the **informal mode of address**
- ***Contáctanos*** Is More of a *relaxed  informal*, or **familiar mode of address**

This is traditionally a very common string used when writing web pages, and like in any written medium, you should follow a consistent mode of address throughout the entire document or page.

Surely everyone will understand the meaning regardless of the mode of address you use, even if you mix them, but doing so will cast a poor or amateurish impression on your readers.

To decide which mode of address is more appropriate for your writing, consider your audience and purpose of the document or web page.

Financial Institutions, Professional associations, and in general, services that have a very low turnaround, will use the formal mode of address, and with good reason! You are entrusting them (say a bank) with your assets, so respectful, factual and unambiguous communication is a must, and that calls for formality.

Public utilities and government sites will use the informal mode to give the impression of a responsible, yet dynamic organization in communications with their customers

If your main audience are young adults and adolescents, or the topic is about their iterests, (videogames, pop  music, sports) then the familiar  mode of address may actually generate more trust amongst them, because you "speak their language"

#### Regional variations

Some Latin American countries in Central America, (Guatemala, El Salvador) and the  Caribbean (Venezuela) have inverted the formal and informal modes of address, an example of this inversion could be

*"Papa, yo a usted le amo con todo el corazón"*. 
Is pretty weird in Mexico, yet correct usage in El Salvador, a father being one of your closest and familiar relatives.

*"Alfredo, apenas te he conocido y no puedo decir que te amo"*. 
would be awkward in Mexico where a couple just met and the formal mode of address is expected until trust and familiarity is established, but would be exactly right in Venezuela, where this mode is used to denote deference, distance or respect.

Comment: note one says _nosotr**o**s_ and the other one _nosotr**a**s_, which gives another parameter to compare.

Comment: Hey I just noticed that too.. so, there are two aspects the question: gender which you cover and mode of address that I immediately noticed since first case says Contact**a** con nosotras and the second says Contact**e** con nosotros, which perhaps compounded the Asker's confusion. It is however customary for this string to be written in the masculine gender, I don't recall ever seeing it online, in the femenine gender, except on the website of the Catholic nuns that ran my school!

Comment: Haha, that's a good one! Exactly, there are two variables here and most probably the most important one is this on mode you are explaining here. I see _contacto_ being used everywhere precisely to avoid the decision on whether to use tú/usted.

Comment: Which I think is pretty lazy on the part of the copywriter... I checked the largest bank around here (Banamex) and everything is addressed formally, Curiously, Banorte; a relatively young and small bank, lately has been catering to young professionals and students, and their copy is all addressed informally xD

Comment: I did a little survey consisting in checking different pages. Most of them shouw _contacto_. I just now discovered [one](http://santander.es/) using _contacta_. I do understand the decision: you want to address a broad set of people and some will like one and others the other. However, for example [El País uses](http://elpais.com/estaticos/contacte/) _contacto_ as a title and then uses _tú_

Comment: Interesting choice by the copywriter, perhaps there is actually no conflict in mode of address there, since "Contacto" Is a totally passive noun, while in declension with a personal pronoun, it becomes a "call to action" which is then further nuanced by the mode of address...